# Cryptographic Provider Development Kit is not found

Tags: cng

On this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal
exists download link to Cryptographic Provider development kit what is broken for some time.

"
If you are developing a CNG cryptographic algorithm provider or key storage provider, you must download the Cryptographic Provider Development Kit from Microsoft.
"

Where I can find it ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft updated their documentation and added the "Cryptographic Provider development kit" download link in Windows CNG documentation again. The Cryptographic Provider development kit can be downloaded using [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30688)